# PHP or JS Templateing engine? (for multiple blocks of the same html)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mustache, handlebars.js

Main questions are in bold at the bottom, But I'll walk you through what and why i'm asking.

Basically taking what i'm now doing for users one-at-a-time, and trying to give them the option of displaying everything on one-page. Was using PHP to place data in html, but interested in improving my code and wondering if a handlebars.js with javascript would make more sense, even just for my own sanity.

Say a user has a list with check box's next to each

```
[x] Option 1
[ ] Option 2
[ ] Option 3
...
[x] Option 20
```

For each box checked, a block of html is displayed with information from the database.

Right now, I only display one block of html per page. PHP was on the same page, grabbing the data, and looping through the 2 arrays generated from two queries, with inline php inside the html to generate the current blocks of html.

```
....
<div class="option-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ( $option_list as $option ) : ?>
....
```

With needing to be able to generate this same block of code between 1 and 20 times on the same page. I guess I could still use php inline and loop over the entire block of html to create another block of html for each selected option.

```
|    Option 1      |  |    Option 20     |
|  Title: Test1    |  |  Title: Test2    |
```

But I was wondering if there is an advantage to using a javascript templating engine for this purpose. I have javascript written to chart data, currently I have hidden html elements that store the php variables (15 of them from two arrays), which is then pulled by my jQuery. But I already feel like hiding variables in html at least feels like bad practice.

```
<div id="total-users" style="display:none;"><?php echo $total_users ?></div>
....
var totalUsers = $('#total-users').html();
```

**This may be one of those, if you had to ask, it probably is bad practice type of questions. But, honestly, is this bad practice?**

**In the interest of writing higher quality code, would this be better done using json_encode after php grabs all of the data. Then to use a javascript template engine like handlebars.js with in a block of html that is cloned for each option that is selected?**

One more thing, I may in the future want to be able to switch the data being displayed on-the-fly using a drop down in each block, does this change which route makes more sense?

Is there anything else obvious that i'm missing, or doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would absolutely recommend using a template for the data.

1- As the user selects an option (or submits their final choices from all available options), make an AJAX call to retrieve a JSON object (you can return one object or all option data in one JSON call, the latter preferred).

2- Use the template (handlebars, moustache, underscore, etc), to render the data in a success callback function.

This will make your code more efficient, and more flexible for future UI requests (your code would support many different implementations from a user experience standpoint).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the information you're retrieving from the database is static (that is, it doesn't change between each checkbox click).

If the above is true, I would personally do it like this. (just my opinion though)

I would grab all information from the database (referring to all "checkboxes") just once, server-side (PHP). Then I would put them in hidden divs:

```
<div id="stuffFromDb1" class="hidden" style="display: none">blablabla</div>
```

Then, when the user clicks in a checkbox, I would show the correspondent div, by changing the display: none to display: block. (with jQuery it's even easier, see [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

This seems to me the most efficient way instead of grabbing the information through AJAX or multiple "forms".

EDIT:

I prefer this method to AJAX and form post because it reduces the number of requests to the server. Unless the DB queries are very CPU intensive (complicated) it is usually faster to query the database once than several times and giving the user a better experience.

Edit2:

It's hard to give you an answer without seeing the code but for 100 or 200 or even 1000, I would bet it would be faster overall to load them all at once than loading them 1 by 1, Specially if you could achieve that doing only 1 query to the database.

Client side template system always relies on the speed of the client. In newer browsers / new PCs JS engine is fairly quick, but for older PCS / older browsers that is not true at all. Complex DOM manipulations + the time needed to complete the AJAX request may take quite a while, a time during which the user may not be able to interact with the page. Besides, other problems might arise (AJAX Race Condition pops into my mind).

Comment: The information being pulled is static here, it's updated elsewhere, but this is more like a report or summary of data. This is definitely a simple method of achieving this. But would it still be efficient if the number shot up. There are some additional javascript that is run for each, displaying a chart. I could run that whenever I set specific blocks to being visible. But if instead of 20 blocks, there's 100 or 200, would this change your mind as far as it being efficient? Just curious. The queries are not complicated, but this feature is not set in stone, so trying to make it flexible.